# Static block non functional

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I have a static block for my main menu. I am unable to make this block working. I need to change the URL for my site main menu, but since this block doesn't work. I am not able to figure out how to do it. Even after deactivating the block, it still shows the main menu, which somewhat means that this block always remains activated.

*Here's the code for the static block*

```
<ul>
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="about-magento-demo-store"}}">about us</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="contacts/"}}">contact us</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="blog"}}">blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Block Title: `Menu Links`
Identifier: `pt_menu_links`

This is the website : [singhcycle.com](http://www.singhcycle.com)
I need to update the link of the main menu (`About Us, Contact Us, Blog`)

Comment: Are you sure the links are coming from a static block. Can you turn on template hints and confirm what template file the menu is using

Comment: Please check if it's on the right store view or website

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this qualifies to be an answer

All i need to do was clear the cache! Sometimes, we overlook the basics, I guess that's what happened with me today.